# How do I map relations in an eventstore used in an eventsourced architecture?

Tags: events, domain-driven-design, aggregate, relationship, event-sourcing

I am trying to wrap my head around structuring relationships in an eventstore. I am all new at eventsourcing so please bear with me. :-)

How should relationships be mapped in an eventstore? Can you please give me some recommendations?

Imagine, I have a domain regarding project management. I have an *aggregate* which is a `Project`. The `Project` *aggregate root* contains `Tasks`, `Documents`, `Files`, `Folders` which are collections of core entities in the `Project`. 
I also have a `ProjectBranch` which can be part of the `Project` aggregate but it could also be looked at independently. In the `ProjectBranch` the previously mentioned collections can be changed, and a `ProjectBranch` can be merged into the `Project` again which updates the collections of the `Project`.

Some of the flow resembles a VCS system.

How should these relations be mapped and which separation of aggregates and aggregate roots should I create?

If the `Project` is the only aggregate, the events (I imagine) look like the following:

- ProjectWasCreated [aggregate]
- ProjectDocumentWasCreated
- ProjectTaskWasCreated
- ProjectBranchWasCreated
- ProjectBranchDocumentWasCreated
  (how will this event e.g. know which branch the Document belongs to)

All events that happen in a `ProjectBranch` will in some way have to be replayed on the Project once the ProjectBranchWasMergedToProject event happens.

On the other hand there could be a more relational structure where there are several separate aggregates - e.g. `Project`, `ProjectBranch`, `Task`, `Document` and so on.

This would mean that the domain has a different set of events which could look like the following:

- ProjectWasCreated [aggregate]
- DocumentWasCreated [aggregate]
- ProjectDocumentWasAttached(documentId)
- ProjectBranchWasCreated(projectId) [aggregate]
- DocumentWasCreated [aggregate]
- ProjectBranchDocumentWasAttached(documentId)

Some of these functionalities might need to work independently outside of the `Project`, so they would be made as standalone modules.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that all these elements are aggregates: `Project`, `ProjectBranch`, `Task`, `Document`, and so on.

One of the basic tenets of constructing Aggregates is that they form a transactional consistency boundary, meaning that within a single Aggregate, all elements must be consistent and satisfy associated business rules at the time of a transaction.

That is why people usually stick with small Aggregate structures, with most Aggregates having just one Entity within them. It is going to be impossible for you to keep all these elements in sync and consistent, as your `Project` grows.

Now onto your question, the answer to relationships is in two parts:

1. All linkages between Aggregates should be in the form of Aggregate identities. If a `Task` is linked to a `Project`, then the `Task` aggregate event will contain `ProjectId` as an attribute.

   You should not store aggregate structures inside one another.

   If you were using an RDBMS, any syncing required between aggregates (if a Project is closed, for example), should be accomplished with the help of Domain Events.

   But since you are using EventSourcing, you don't need to do this in the background. You dynamically construct the aggregate structure, which brings us to the second point.
2. Like any other EventSource projection, when you construct an aggregate object, you will need to reconstitute the internal data elements.

   If you want the Project structure to be available as part of your Task projection, you make a call to the Project Application Service to retrieve the Project Aggregate in realtime.

   So on and so forth for all linked Aggregates that you may want as part of your projection.

Comment: Thanks, Subhash. I'm trying to fully understand your answer. I was of the impression, that an event payload could not contain relation references.This might be (very) wrong. A couple of follow-up questions are posted below:

Comment: If the payload contains references to another aggregate, how will I make sure, that the base aggregate is not changed from the "outside"? Is that through projection?

Comment: 2) If I'm imagining an aggregate where the aggregate representation in the domain has a parent type and a child type, do I then store the aggregate type as well? Meaning that I would have the following fields per event: aggregate_id, aggregate_type, event, event_version, sequence_number, payload, actor_id, timestamp.

Comment: 1. Yes, correct. Each aggregate will be associated with a separate event stream. If you have references to a Task in a Project's event steam, you build up the task object from its event stream ignoring references to itself. In the past, to accomplish this at scale, I found the best way to was to create a rolling snapshot. A snapshot is a projection of the current state of an aggregate at a given point and represents the state when all events to that point have been replayed. You use rolling snapshots as a heuristic to prevent the need to load all events for the entire history of an aggregate.

Comment: 2. There is no need to store the `aggregate_type` if you have separate streams, one per aggregate. Can you elaborate with an example, for me to understand better?

Comment: Ad. 2. I found this post (https://cqrs.wordpress.com/documents/building-event-storage/) with at great explanation on the storage structure, and I see that in an RDBMS it is suggested to store the aggregates in a separate table. This might be what I'm looking for. My thought was, that if I have a Project aggregate and in my domain a ConstructionProject is a child of the Project, it would be necessary to store the aggregate type in order to identify the projections to make over each type of aggregrate. But I guess, if aggregates are stored separately, then I will know the type from that table.

Comment: Ad. 1. If a Task can belong to a Project or a ConstructionProject, would you then make it a Task aggregate and use validation (and a payload reference) to verify the relation in the domain, or would you make the Task a ProjectTask or a ContructionProjectTask as an aggregate?